# Save Extra from intent between 3 activities

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities. A, B, C.
I set a string by getExtra from intent in activity B from activity A.
I need to get another extra from activity C, then get back to activity B.

but after i get back to activity B, i lost the Extra from activity A.
I tried to use savedPreferenced, change the launch to singleTop.
but then my app crashed.
how to save the extra from intent?

I can't find a full tutorial to do it.

i'm newbie, need some detail explanations. thanks.

this is the code i used to send extra from activity A to B :

```
    void sendTxt() {
    String shareBody = getPlainDocumentText();
    if (shareBody == null) {
        Toast.makeText(A.this, R.string.empty_document, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    String txt = shareBody;
    i.putExtra("file", txt);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    Screen.unlockOrientation(A.this);
}
```

this is code i used to getExtra in B from A :

```
 public String teks;
 if (savedInstanceState == null){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras==null){
            teks = null;
        }else{
            teks = extras.getString("file");
        }
    }else{
        teks = (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("file");
    }
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    t.setText(teks);
```

then i move from activity B to C :

```
Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

In activity C, i get back to B and send an extra to B :

```
Intent i = new Intent(C.this, B.class);
String path = dir.getAbsolutePath().toString();
i.putExtra("dir", path);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

In B i received extra from C, but lost the extra from A.

I can't show the log because i didn't use emulator. i simply test my app by creating apk because my laptop doesn't support virtual emulator

Comment: Please share your code with us.

Comment: plz paste ur getextra code , and error log.

Comment: updated.. those are my codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You lost extra's value from A in B after you call B activity from C because you finish(destroy) B activity so the value does lost and recreate the B activity by calling from C activity.

For this problem you can save your value in Shared Pref like.

Save it in Preference in Activity A

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("your_pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("key_name", extra_value);
editor.commit();
```

Get it in Activity B

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("your_pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String name = prefs.getString("key_name", "");
```

Hope this will help you.